# Using Realm in a Cordova plugin for Android

Tags: android, cordova, realm

I am experimenting with using Realm in place of SQLite in my hybrid Android/Cordova app which uses one custom - i.e. written by me - plugin.  From the [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest) I have figured out that this has to be a two step process

- Instructing Gradle to use the Realm plugin which I am doing via my `plugin.xml` file as `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2`
- "Applying the plugin" which according to the documentation involves issuing a `apply plugin: 'realm-android' from the application level`build.gradle`file.

It is not clear to me how I do the latter.  I tried putting the "apply plugin" statement in a build-extras.gradle file only to have Gradle complain

> plugin with id 'realm-android' not found.  Clearly, I am doing something wrong here.  I'd be grateful to anyone who might be able to put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to destroy your delusions, but this assumption is just wrong:

> - Instructing Gradle to use the Realm plugin which I am doing via my `plugin.xml` file as `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2`

---

I'd expect that to be required for the root project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

As well as the module level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "realm-android"

...
dependencies {

    // only this one line can be added through plugin.xml
    implementation "io.realm:realm-android-library:6.0.2"
}
```

However, I think that Cordova by default only supports adding Java dependencies through `plugin.xml`, but no Gradle plugins - therefore you'd likely need to patch both `build.gradle` on demand, with a script similar to [patchAndroidGradle.js](https://github.com/airamrguez/cordova-plugin-realm/blob/master/hooks/patchAndroidGradle.js), hooked into `before_plugin_install`. This obviously would then also need to be un-patched again, upon `before_plugin_uninstall`.

Answer (score 1):

@MartinZeitler's answer is what put me on the right track here.  For a Cordova project here is what you need to do:

**Step 1**
Open the `platoforms/android/app/build.gradle` file and in the `dependencies{..}` section add `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2"`.

**Step 2**
Now open the `platforms\android\build-extras.gradle` file - this is not created by default in Cordova so you might have to create a new one - and enter the following text

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {apply plugin: 'realm-android'}
```

Save the two files and perform a full rebuild of your project.

A few words of explanation are in order here.  The mistake I had made was thinking that what was being supplied by Realm was a Java library.  Not true.  What you do in Realm is to model your data in the form of subclassed [RealmObjects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html).  Typically you will have multiple sub-classes of this type to fully define your data model.  These sub-classes with their annotations are in effect instructions to Realm where you tell it how you are going to manage your data.  As noted in the Realm docs

> An annotation processor will create a proxy class for your RealmObject subclass.

The plugin you are incorporating into your project here is a **Gradle plugin** which extends the capabilities of Gradle.  In this instance it is allowing the Realm annotation processor to examine your data model classes and create its own proxy classes. You can read up on how Gradle uses plugins [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add at the bottom :

`apply plugin: 'realm-android'` in the file `build.gradle` which is under the app folder of your project

Comment: As a general rule with Cordova one is supposed to modify Gradle instructions in a `build-extras.gradle` file as opposed to editing `build.gradle` directly.  In any case I tried what you suggest but with precisely the same resullt - ìd 'real-android' not found